# How to wait for async method to finish in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, edgejs

For the following code (using EdgeJS module), I want to wait for asynchronous method `Start` to complete before writing `sw.Elapsed`, how should I do it?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EdgeJs;
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    [STAThread]
    static  void Main()
    {
        //            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //            Application.Run(new Form1());

        Stopwatch sw =new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
        //wait for start to complete --- how should I do it??
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }


    public static async void Start()
    {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"
        var esprima = require('esprima');
        var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');

        var esprimaast = esprima.parse('var a=1;', { loc: true });
        var esprimaStr = stringify(esprimaast, { space: 3 });
        return function (data, callback) {
            callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + esprimaStr);
        }
    ");

        Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
        //Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make that `Start` method to return a `Task` instead of void. Then you can wait for it easily - `Start().Wait();`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks that work, consider post that as answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can't await `async void` operations neither you should use `async void` except for async event handlers.

`async void` has several issues when you misuse it. exceptions thrown inside an `async void` won't be caught my regular means and will in most cases crash your application.

You should always use `async Task` or `async Task<T>` when you expect a return value.

See this [MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for a few guidelines with `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app) you might use

```
sw.Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult;
```

or

```
Task.WaitAll(sw.Start());
```

Answers from [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) and [SnOrfus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48553/snorfus) respectively. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that Everything originates from the synchronous Main() method. If you want to write asynchronous code then a good way to start would be to make an asynchronous Main method and write your programs code there instead ([i answered a similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34379722/4762137)).

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task mainTask = MainAsync(args);
        mainTask.Wait();
        // Instead of writing more code here, use the MainAsync-method as your new Main()
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        // Write your programs code here, You can freely use the async / await pattern
    }
}
```

That in combination with allowing your "Start" method to return a Task like this:

```
public static async Task Start()
{
    var func = Edge.Func(@"
        var esprima = require('esprima');
        var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');

        var esprimaast = esprima.parse('var a=1;', { loc: true });
        var esprimaStr = stringify(esprimaast, { space: 3 });
        return function (data, callback) {
            callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + esprimaStr);
        }
    ");

    Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));

    //Console.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

would allow you to call your Start method in the MainAsync method like this:

```
static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await Start();
    //wait for start to complete --- how should I do it??
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

I have not been able to test this since i have no clue where that static "Edge" class comes from. But it's a good Place to start methinks.